# Nginx geo module won't use variables?

Tags: nginx, geo

As I try to run nice [Ip2Geo Importer](https://github.com/m-messiah/ip2geo) to add geo functionality to my site, I noticed strange nginx 1.13.6 behavior. I'm in doubt if this is something intended, or I have a way out to use.

Here is the config sample:

```
geo $city {
    ranges;
    default $city_mm;
    include geo/city.txt;
}

geo $city_mm {
    ranges;
    include geo/mm_city.txt;
}
```

that is, it should return content of **`$city_mm`** if value of **`$city`** can not be calculated/found, but as I run it with nginx, it returns just string `$city_mm` (exactly this string, not the content of the variable of that name), while `$city_mm` is defined at that time!

I can't see issues concerning this so just wanted to ask if I have a way to do that, maybe in different way?

Comment: I have the same issue. Couldn't find a solution yet.

Comment: @Carl Author has added syntax to the project description so please take it: https://github.com/m-messiah/ip2geo/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 3):

So so summarize the solution from @alexander's external link, Nginx does not (currently) support dynamic defaults for geo maps, so you have to use the default feature of the regular map instead.

```
geo $city_geo {
    ranges;
    include geo/city.txt;
}

geo $city_mm {
    ranges;
    include geo/mm_city.txt;
}

map $city_geo $city {
    "" $city_mm;
    default $city_geo;
}
```